# Making a recursive function

Tags: function-construction, recursion, iterators

Suppose I have the following functions:

```
a[x_] := x
b[x_] := x (a[x]) - a[x] + 1
c[x_] := x (b[x]) - b[x] + 1
d[x_] := x (c[x]) - c[x] + 1
```

as you can see each function uses previous function to calculate the output. I wonder how can I write a generalised version of this so I can tell the function the number of iteration and it returns the outputs?

**Update:** I made the following:

```
f[x_] := x
Fold[f[#2][#] &, x (f[x]) - f[x] + 1, Range[5]] // ExpandAll
```

Which indeed works, yet I dont know how to expand the results as a list, 
so far it returns:

```
5[4[3[2[1[1 - x + x^2]]]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
f[0, x_] := x
f[i_, x_] := x (f[i - 1, x]) - f[i - 1, x] + 1
```

The idea is to add a second parameter to the function to specify the "level" of the recursion. Then we simply need a base case (here given by `f[0, x_] := x`), and we are done. You can verify that this yields the same result as your original functions:

```
d[x] == f[3, x]
(* True *)
```

An alternative is to use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to solve for an explicit formula for `f[i, x]`:

```
g[i_, x_] = f[i] /. First@RSolve[{f[0] == x, f[i] == x (f[i - 1]) - f[i - 1] + 1}, 
 f[i], i]
(* (-1 + (-1 + x)^i - 2 (-1 + x)^i x + (-1 + x)^i x^2)/(-2 + x) *)
```

Again, we can verify that this is correct:

```
f[5, x] == g[5, x] // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```